# How do I align it to the center with the Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I built personal projects and have problems with Flexbox. I can do it smoothly with space-between in a three-element case, but I could not do it with two elements.

I want to **center the logo on the screen**, *leaving the left side blank*. There are items on the right, but **I cannot align the logo exactly**.

How can I center this logo to cover items?

=> What I'm trying (not center)
[image]

**=> What I want (center)**
[image]

**CodeSandbox Example**: [**Here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-curran-t2085)

Comment: plz check if class header__brand has any right margin set in css ?

Comment: Seeing your screenshots, actually the first one looks centered to me. If you consider the space between logo and search input.

Comment: i did it with position absolute. thanks everyone.